# Update has_many attributes with irregular params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model `LoanPlan` and `Career`, they are associated by a join_table

The request params from another frontend developer will be like this

```
 "loan_plan" => {
                  "id" => 32,
             "careers" => [
        [0] {
                     "id" => 8,
        },
        [1] {
                     "id" => 9,
        }
    ]
},
```

However, I got `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Career(#70198754219580) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70198701106200)` in the `update` method

```
def update
  @loan_plan.update(loan_plan_params)
end
```

When I tried to update the loan_plan model with careers params, it expects the params["careers"] should be `careers object of a array` instead of ids of a array.

So my workround is to manually fectch the careers objects of a array and replace the sanitized params.

It seems dirty and smells bad, any better solution in Rails way? Thanks

```
def loan_plan_params
  # params.fetch(:loan_plan, {})
  cleaned_params = params.require(:loan_plan).permit(
    :id, 
    :name, 
    {:careers=>:id}
  )
  cleaned_params["careers"] = Career.find(cleaned_params["careers"].map{|t| t["id"]})
  cleaned_params
end
```

## model

```
class LoanPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :careers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :careers
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails way, `params` should be

```
"loan_plan" => {
  "id" => "32",
  "career_ids" => ["8", "9"]
}
```

and the strong parameter `loan_plan_params` should be

```
def loan_plan_params
  params.require(:loan_plan).permit(
    :id,
    :name,
    :career_ids => []
  )
end
```